# In react, how to use condition to create a custom search functionality?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state of projects which is of type an array that contains the following data.

[image: projects array]

Using this data, I need to filter the user's result based on search input that matches with `company_name`, `project_name`, `project_description`, `release_name`, and `release's description`

```
this.state = {
  projects: [],
  searchfield: ''
};

onSearchChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ searchfield: event.target.value })
}

<input type="text" placeholder="Search" className="form-control search-input" onChange={this.onSearchChange.bind(this)} />

render() {
    return(
        const filterProjects = this.state.projects.filter(data => {
            // filter projects based on project's name
          return data.project_name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
        })
    )
}
```

At the moment, I am only able to filter the result according to keywords that matches with project's name.

Hw can I use other properties or add a condition to filter data based on other properties as well?

Comment: Do you mean match any of those fields with a single search term? Or match each field with it's own input? Your filtering criteria is not well detailed

Comment: Seconding @charlietfl's question, but if it is one field -- is this an OR or an AND in terms of where the search term could be? I'm assuming it's OR, as in: for searchTerm = "foo", show projects where project_name OR project_description OR release_name OR release_description OR company_name includes searchTerm, right?

Comment: @BenjaminRobinson yes, that's exactly what I am looking to do. If I search for "foo" in the input box, then it should check if any of these (project_name, project_description, release_name, release_description, company_name) contain the word foo and return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see if a term exists in any of those fields you can use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
const filterFields = ['company_name', 'project_name', 'project_description', 'release_name', 'descrip'];

const { projects, searchfield) = this.state;

const term = searchfield.toLowerCase(); 

const filterProjects = projects.filter(data => {  
  return filterFields.some(field => data[field].toLowerCase().includes(term))
});
```

Comment: I tried to implement this to my project, but its giving me an error saying that `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

Comment: Could modify it to `(data[field] || '').toLowerCase().includes(term)`